# Compilation of the access modifiers

Tags: c#, access-modifiers

What is the difference in the compiled code between a private or a protected and a public class member? Is there any check during runtime whether one can access the member or not? I am asking these questions in context of C#.

Comment: There is a similar discussion about readonly here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/913400/is-there-any-run-time-overhead-to-readonly

Comment: @doctorlove to comment your deleted answer, according to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15564011/oop-access-modifiers-copmile-time-or-run-time) there is a runtime check in Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After compilation to IL, the information is preserved. A compiled module (DLL) can be referenced by other code and then private/public/protected do matter.

After compilation from IL to native machine code, there is no difference.

> Is there any check during runtime whether one can access the member or not?

I'm not totally sure but I would think this is part of the Type-loader. Code that (w/o Reflection) accesses a private variable that it shouldn't know about has to break a rule somewhere.

Comment: Access is checked when JIT starts to compile method, it will throw exception if method tries to access hidden from it member.